# Retrieving specific keywords from a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

Given a line of string, I need a way **to extract keywords**.

A `keyword` is *anything that starts with **$*** and *ends when it is followed by non-alphanumeric character*.

For instance, given the following strings

```
tempval = $SREAD(13,"B14.OATEMP");
$ORCONTROL("B14.OUTT)
$LOOP(0,"B14.HX.COM)
if ($START(24))
```

I need to retrieve $SREAD, $ORCONTROL, $LOOP, $START

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this pattern, it might help you

```
\$[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: The program in the screenshot, RegexBuddy, is fantastic.

Comment: @BradWerth aside from being fantastic, the program is a great tool to learn Regex. :D

Comment: No doubt about it. If everyone had this tool, the #regex questions on this site would be reduced significantly, I suspect.